# Dynamically create lists of lists from CSV file data

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a `CSV` file that I want am `reading` as a configuration file to create a `list` of `lists` to store data in.

The format of my `CSV` file is:

```
list_name, search_criteria  
channel1, c1  
channel2, c2  
channel3, c3
```

I want to `read` in the `CSV` file and dynamically create the `list` of `lists` from the `list_name` data as it could grow and shrink over time and I always want whatever is defined in the `CSV` file.

The `list_name` in the CSV file is a "prefix" to the list name i want to create dynamically.  For example, read in "channel1", "channel2", "channel3" from the csv file and create a lists of lists where "mainList[]" is the core list and contains 3 lists within it named "channel1_channel_list", "channel2_channel_list", "channel3_cannel_list".

I realize my naming conventions could be simplified so please disregard.  I'll remain once i have a working solution.  I will be using the search criteria to populate the lists within `mainLists[]`.

Here is my incomplete code:

```
mainList = []

with open('list_config.csv') as input_file:
    dictReader = csv.DictReader(input_file)

    for row in dictReader:
        listName = row['list_name'] + '_channel_list'
```

Comment: Don't create a list of lists, create a dict of lists, using the names the keys.

Comment: Thank you.  I am a python newbie and am not sure how to do that.  Can you offer an example?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to read your data and create a dict from it.

As well as reading data from files, the `csv` readers can read their data from a list of strings, which is handy for example code like this. With your data you need to specify `skipinitialspace=True` to skip over the spaces after the commas.

```
import csv

data = '''\
list_name, search_criteria
channel1, c1
channel2, c2
channel3, c3
'''.splitlines()

dictReader = csv.DictReader(data, skipinitialspace=True)

main_dict = {}
for row in dictReader:
    name = row['list_name'] + '_channel_list'
    criteria = row['search_criteria']
    main_dict[name] = criteria

# Print data sorted by list_name
keys = sorted(main_dict)
for k in keys:
    print(k, main_dict[k])
```

**output**

```
channel1_channel_list c1
channel2_channel_list c2
channel3_channel_list c3
```

This code is a little more complicated than Joe Iddon's version, but it's a little easier to adapt if you have more than two entries per row. OTOH, if you do only have two entries per row then you should probably use Joe's simpler approach.

Comment: +1 For the clever `skipinitialspace`, I have only used the `csv` `module` a couple of times, and that is a cool trick (and of course the mention of me **:)**)

Answer (score 1):

Load in the `file` in a `with` `statement`, then use `csv.reader` which `returns` a `reader object`. This can then be converted to a `dictionary` by passing it into `dict()`:

```
with open('list_config.csv') as input_file:
    dictionary = dict(csv.reader(input_file))
```

Now, the contents of `dictionary` is:

```
{'channel3': ' c3', 'channel1': ' c1', 'channel2': ' c2'}
```